# Trying to terminate the loop early

Tags: python, string, loops, mysql-python

This is a code I wrote that will take the values from a CSV file and make it into a MySQL database. All the entries in the CSV file are string values.

```
entries = ""
counter = 1

with open('dataset.csv') as file_obj:
    heading = next(file_obj)
    reader_obj = csv.reader(file_obj)
    for row in reader_obj:
        #print(row)
        for value in row:
            #print(value)
            entries = entries + "'" + value + "'" + ","
            #print(entries)
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='test', user='root', password='********')

            sql_insert_stmt = "insert into diseases values(" + entries + " '' );"

            print(sql_insert_stmt)
            
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            result = cursor.execute(sql_insert_stmt)
            print(f"inserted {counter} entry")
            counter += counter



        except mysql.connector.Error as error:
            print("Failed to add value in MySQL: {}".format(error))
```

In the above code, this loop is running 1 more time than I need it, and therefore `entries` is storing all the values of a row twice.

```
    for value in row:
        #print(value)
        entries = entries + "'" + value + "'" + ","
        #print(entries)
```

How do I make sure that the loop stops running and terminates 1 iteration early or can I remove the latest appended string from the variable?

Comment: `for idx, value in enumerate(row): if idx < len(row) - 1:` or, since your loop doesn't seem to be doing anything other than this one line, simply `for value in row[:-1]` without the if.

Comment: How about `f'insert into diseases values {row};'` and let python build parentheses with values? Use `row[:-1]` to omit last value.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for doing it line by line? It can be done with pandas `read_csv` and `to_sql` in nearly two lines

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='test', user='root', password='********')

data = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')
data.to_sql('my_table', conn, if_exists='append', index = False)
```

Comment: I need the table in MySQL because I plan on using this in a different Java project.

Comment: Sorry i've overseen that. But MySQL should behave similar [as it is compliant with PEP 249](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-introduction.html) . I have updated my answer for MySql. The quesiton is, why not use pandas but making single sql insert instead?

Comment: I tried the `.to_sql` but it throws me this error. `DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement`

Comment: `AND name=?` this seems like you didn't specify the tablename (should be `AND name=diseases ` in your case). However, i don't see your code that trows the error, nor your exact database schema, so it's hard to tell the cause.

Comment: Anyway, regarding your loop problem. If it isn't solved yet, you should provide more info. How does the csv look? What is the print(entries) after the loop? How does your table diseases look (how it should and how it is)?